# creating multiple screen resolution Code base UI for android

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my First question on Stack and So sorry for my bad english.
I am working on Android app in which i have to design code based ui (No xml ui or layout)  what i have done so far is i have created different class for different controls like for button i have a custom button class in which i have my own method to create button. now the problems came  to handling width and height and position of any ui control on different screen sizes.  Can any body help me how to do that.
I already created method to detect what type of screen and its height and width but still no success .
Please Help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you having a working layout withyour custom component and looking for a way to handle orientation to change this layout ?

Comment: @Guian i have working layout with my custom component and yes i want a better way to handle layout and its component on orientation change as well as on different screen resolution like Mobile as well as tab version screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override [onConfigurationChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) on activity to handle orientation change:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig){
           int orientation_default = newConfig.orientation;
            switch (orientation_default) {
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT: {
                //change your layout according to orientation

                break;
            }
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE: {
               //change your layout according to orientation

                break;
            }

}
```

Its is a solution, but if your are going to develop more and more on android you really should consider building your ui with xml layouts, its more easy to handle config change since its done for that.

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks again @Guian but i have already handle  component to adjust on  on Configuration Change but i have to adjust it on all screen resolution  and my requirement is to create all layout at run time using code